# Get interfaceId from interface in ethers js or hardhat

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, interfaces, function-selector

Solidity has this wonderful way to quickly get the interface id from  an interface. Suppose I have the interface

```
interface undernose {
    function overmouth() external;
}
```

then solidity (at least in version 0.8.0 and above) has this wonderful function `type(...).interfaceId`, which can be applied to our interface `bytes4 id = type(undernose).interfaceId` to yield `id = 0x963ca2ef`.

Is there a convenient way in ethers js to achieve the same thing. Or maybe hardhat has some sort of abstraction that does it?

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple app with the objective of making this easier, https://interfaceid.lucasgrasso.com.ar/ , you just have to paste the interface ABI, hope its useful!

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @stevyhacker, fixed it. It was failing because of the change in Heroku pricing plans. Sorry for the inconvenience.